# Get certain element range in a List<long> based on some conditions

Tags: list, search, c#-4.0

- I have 2 `List<long>` (`valueCov` and `valueWat`) with `long` data typed values.
- When a certain list element is not found I need to get the next
  closer element with least different of the searching value.

**For that:**

- I'm iterating through valueWat's elements(x) and if there is no exact
  match for it in `valueCov`,then into that else part I need to find the
  very closest element to "x".
- I need a solution/method of finding closest next element from that
  `List`.

Code Segment:

```
foreach (var y in sortedCov){
                    valueCov.Add(y.Value);
                }
                //Console.WriteLine("initial" + valueCov.Count);
                foreach (var x in valueWat){
                    //foreach (var y in valueCov){
                       // var keys = new List<long>(y.Value);
                            int index = valueCov.BinarySearch(x);
                            int lower;
                            int upper;
                                if (index >= 0) {
                                  lower = upper = index;
                                  blockedWaterCoverMap.Add(x, valueCov[index]);
                                  valueCov.RemoveAt(index);
                                                }
                                else  {
                                    //foreach (var y in valueCov){
                                        //subListCov = valueCov.FindAll((y < x + 7) && (y > x - 7));
                                       // }

                                      }
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly You want a function like this:

```
int FindClosest(long data) {
        int i = 0; // index of currently checked element from valueCov
        int index = i; // returned index of the closest element 
        // here is current lowest distance to searched value:
        long min = long.MaxValue; 
        // currently counted difference between input value
        // and the next element of the list valueCov
        long diff = 0; 
        foreach (var elem in valueCov) {
            if ((diff = Math.Abs(elem - data)) <= min) {
                min = diff;
                index = i; // the searched index is updated
            }
            i++; 
        }

        // random selection of the index from the closest
        // found values
        List<int> indices = new List<int>();
        for (int n = 0; n < valueCov.Length; n++) {
             if (valueCov[n] == valueCov[index])
                indices.Add(n);
        }
        Random r = new Random();
        index = indices[r.Next(indices.Count)];
        return index;
}
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: There is an issue. When the valueCov consists same value more than once;  like: valueCov { 25,25,34,34,34,.....} Then, the index is pointing out the first occurance always.

Comment: I assumed that it doesn't matter as You are looking for an index of the closest value.If you want last found index that fits Your conditions You may change the if statement to accept also the values equal to minimum so: if ((diff = Math.Abs(elem - data)) <= min). Suppose You want a randoml minimum value index than after the foreach loop there should be a search for all elements that have the found minimal value and save them in a new array of type integer. Than You can randomly choose the index (see update of the answer).

Comment: Ya Fine. What is that "d" mentioned here? for (int n = 0; n < d.Length; n++) {
             if (d[n] == d[index])
                indices.Add(n);

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Of course I meant valueCov, not any d...variable d was in my implementation where I was testing if the code works. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Oops i'm afraid.Still the same duplicate key Exception is appearing when i add that value returned into a dictionary.

Comment: returning index has duplicate values such that ( many valueWat x matches with one index of valueCov) .